# How much time, in crotchet beats, does a crotchet triplet take up?

Tags: theory, rhythm, tuplet

Please help me with my gcse music homework!! Here is the question I've been given;

How much time, in crotchet beats, does a crotchet triplet take up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A triplet figure is assumed to have a 2:3 ratio of metric duration to notated duration under the triplet.

Remember that you can derive many of these rhythmic rules yourself by examining real music. A measure of 2/4 time, for example, will always contain a full half note of rhythmic duration: never more, never less. If a measure of printed music contains three eighth notes under a triplet plus two more eighth notes, you can set up a little rhythmic algebraic equation as follows:

```
3<triplet eighth> + 2eighth = half
```

Then solve for `<triplet eighth>`! A `half = 4eighth`, so if you subtract out the `2eighth` from each side, you get:

```
3<triplet eighth> = 2eighth
```

Then divide each side by 3:

```
<triplet eighth> = (2/3)eighth
```

Who says algebra isn't useful for musicians? :-)

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UIKGV2cTgqA